# Firebase querying

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have searched everywhere but am not able to figure this out.
I understand that nested querying is possible, but I am trying to use the result in `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which seems to accept only a single query.

Below is the stucture of the database in JSON, I need know how to query all the users who are near a particular location(based on the 'location') and retrieve their details from 'users'

```
{
  "user_location" : {
    "bqKoBzNSb8apOZxzGk2PL7hpFuU2" : {
      "lati" : 16.537221908569336,
      "longi" : 80.63591003417969,
      "timestamp" : "17:19:36"
    },
    "z6jjD4t0SjNrqR6EU3aU39vH5iB3" : {
      "lati" : 16.537214279174805,
      "longi" : 80.63591766357422,
      "timestamp" : "09:34:24"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "8t4sVwfFl1RuXAgzOTihc9D4YhM2" : {
      "age" : 18,
      "bloodType" : "A-",
      "email" : "zxcv@gmail.com",
      "phnum" : "9502524713",
      "username" : "zxcv"
    },
    "bqKoBzNSb8apOZxzGk2PL7hpFuU2" : {
      "age" : 0,
      "email" : "sckool@gmail.com",
      "username" : "sckool"
    },
    "iexFcGrrztc81D3xpui67tYuim22" : {
      "age" : 18,
      "bloodType" : "A-",
      "email" : "abcd@gmail.com",
      "phnum" : "9502452413",
      "username" : "abcd"
    },
    "z6jjD4t0SjNrqR6EU3aU39vH5iB3" : {
      "age" : 18,
      "email" : "qwer@gmail.com",
      "username" : "qwer"
    }
  },
  "users_active" : {
    "8t4sVwfFl1RuXAgzOTihc9D4YhM2" : {
      "age" : 18,
      "bloodType" : "A-",
      "email" : "zxcv@gmail.com",
      "phnum" : "9502524713",
      "username" : "zxcv"
    },
    "bqKoBzNSb8apOZxzGk2PL7hpFuU2" : {
      "age" : 0,
      "email" : "sckool@gmail.com",
      "username" : "sckool"
    },
    "iexFcGrrztc81D3xpui67tYuim22" : {
      "age" : 18,
      "bloodType" : "A-",
      "email" : "abcd@gmail.com",
      "phnum" : "9502452413",
      "username" : "abcd"
    },
    "z6jjD4t0SjNrqR6EU3aU39vH5iB3" : {
      "age" : 0,
      "email" : "qwer@gmail.com",
      "username" : "qwer"
    }
  }
}
```

The code below creates the RecyclerView

```
 tm=getTree();

    Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, PostViewHolder>(User.class, R.layout.item_post,
            PostViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final User model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            Log.d(TAG,"populateViewHolder");
            final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
            System.out.println(postKey);

            });

         // Bind Post to ViewHolder
                viewHolder.bindToPost(model, postKey, getTree());

        }


    };

    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I get the query for the code below

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    final String myUserId = getUid();

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("user_location");

    ref.orderByKey().equalTo(myUserId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            myloc = dataSnapshot.getValue(Locat.class);
            latFrom=myloc.lati;
            lngFrom=myloc.longi;
           }});

        ref.orderByKey().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            otherloc = dataSnapshot.getValue(Locat.class);
            latTo = otherloc.lati;
            lngTo = otherloc.longi;
            dist = getDistanceInfo();

            if ( dist<10 && dataSnapshot.getKey()!=myUserId ) {

                tm.put(dist, dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }
        }

    });


    Query donors= databaseReference.child("users").orderByKey();

    return donors;
 }
```

SO i query from users in 'FirebaserecyclerAdapter' and get all nearby users in the 'getQuery' and put them in a 'TreeMap', but how do i check every key against keys present in the Map??

Comment: You'll have to use [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) to retrieve the keys of users in the region you're interested in and then load each user in turn based on their key.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  isn't there any other way to do this? I've actually managed to get keys and store them in a List. But I am not able to stop the 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter' from iterating over every entry in "users".

Comment: You should also evaluate `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter`, which is a variant on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. It allows you to do parent/child queries. Some combination of `GeoFire` and `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` is probably what you want.

Comment: @ChadRobinson I am unable to find docs for 'FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter'. I am finding it hard to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Docs for the `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` are here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data. If you're having trouble making something work, share the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).